# Batch script to fetch each line from a .txt file as a string (more than one word in a line) and google search each string in a separate tab in chrome

Tags: command-line, batch-file, google-search, string, array

I've a controlfile.txt file in which I have some softwares names in each line, e.g. "Microsoft Office" in first line, then "Autodesk AutoCAD" in second line, "Adobe Acrobat Reader" in third line and so on. I need a batch script to fetch each line from that .txt file as a string (more than one word in a line) and google search each string (Software Name) in a separate tab for its license terms or EULA. I've this the following code, but it is not passing the value of array as a query for google search.

```
@echo off 
set "file=C:\New folder\controlfile.txt" 
set /A i=0 
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do ( 
set /A i+=1 
call set array[%%i%%]=%%a 
call set n=%%i%% 
) 
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do ( 
call echo %%array[%%i]%% 
start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q=%%array[%%i]%%+EULA 
)
```

Comment: Does it open anything in chrome? You've got something that converts spaces to +'s?

Comment: @Xen2050 I have 4 line items in controlfile.txt, so when I run this batch script, Chrome opens 4 tabs and search for "%array[1]% EULA", "%array[2]% EULA", "%array[3]% EULA", "%array[4]% EULA" respectively in each tab. But I want that chrome searches for the value that is stored in "%array[1]% " and so on.

Comment: You need to use Delayed Expansion. See [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time and also see my answer [Windows CMD script to count files and get filenames](//superuser.com/a/1181398) which shows how to correctly simulate arrays in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? I don't see any need to store the values in an array - you can simply launch each chrome tab directly within a single simple FOR /F loop.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("C:\New folder\controlfile.txt") do (
  echo %%~A
  start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q="%%~A"+EULA
)
```

The reason why your array based code failed is because you forgot to use CALL with your START line.

```
call start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q=%%array[%%i]%%+EULA
```

I much prefer using delayed expansion instead of the CALL trick, as delayed expansion is much faster.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file=C:\New folder\controlfile.txt"
set /a i=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%file%") do (
  set /a i+=1
  set "array[!i!]=%%A"
)
for /L %%A in (1,1,%i%) do (
  echo !array[%%A]!
  start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q=!array[%%A]!+EULA
)
```

Assuming none of your lines begin with `:`, you can do the first loop without CALL or DelayedExpansion

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do set "array[%%A]=%%B"
```